# Foci Concentric Circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections

[image]

My approach: Using the foci formula $$c=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$$. By plugging in $a=3$ and $b=2$ I obtain plus and minus $\sqrt{5}$. But there's 2 choices with a root 5 result. How do i know which one is which?

Comment: Since you have the correct formula, why do you need to downgrade the result of using it to a "conjecture"?

Comment: Sorry I did plug in a for 3 and b for 2...got the root 5 result.

Comment: x @User: Yes. Why do you call that a "conjecture" rather than "the result of using the correct formula on the data, and therefore the correct answer"?

Comment: I didn't know it was the correct answer...it was my guess.

Comment: x @User: When you know the formula to use and which numbers to insert it in, then by which imaginable reason do you call the result a "guess" rather than "knowledge"?

Comment: I didn't know if that was the proper way of doing the problem. This is why I posted it. I wasn't exactly sure. Get me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the figure, $a$ is $3$ and $b$ is $2$. Assuming the center of the circles are at the origin, $c=\pm \sqrt{5}$. Where are you stuck?

Comment: There's 2 choices for that, B and D. That's where. 10+ years since I see something like this.

Comment: Ok, perhaps you should take a look at how the [cartesian coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) works. Admitting the origin at the center, can you see that the foci are in the $x$-axis? Can you see, then, that their first coordinate is zero (because they are in the $x$-axis)?

Comment: lol wow *slap in the face* it's the little things that confuse me thanks for clearing that up.